# Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, dynamodb-queries

Basically, I have a table with two indexes that I'm trying to query and filter.
The querying part works for the Table and the index but the problem happens when I try to filter:

```
ValidationException: Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {QueryFilter} Expression parameters: {KeyConditionExpression}
```

Here are the params passed to docClient.query():

```
{
  TableName: 'MyTable',
  Limit: 15,
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  IndexName: 'user-date-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#user = :yyyy',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#user': 'user' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':yyyy': 'the_user_id' },
  QueryFilter: { status: { AttributeValueList: [Array], ComparisonOperator: 'EQ' } }
}
```

When I call the query with the same params but without the QueryFilter, I get correct results, but I still need to filter (by status in this case, and I have about 5 other options to filter with).

I've spent a few hours trying different things and the AWS docs are not clear enough and no examples are presented, I've spent a whole day to even get to that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QueryFilter` is considered a [Legacy Conditional Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.html). From the previous link:

> With the introduction of expression parameters (see [Using Expressions in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.html)), several older parameters have been deprecated. New applications should not use these legacy parameters, but should use expression parameters instead.

The documentation for [`QueryFilter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.QueryFilter.html) recommends using [`FilterExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.QueryFilter.html#w20aac38c23c27c17) instead.

With FilterExpression, your query may look similar to this:

```
{
  TableName: 'MyTable',
  Limit: 15,
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  IndexName: 'user-date-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#user = :yyyy',
  FilterExpression: '#status = :status',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#user': 'user', '#status': 'status' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':yyyy': 'the_user_id', ':status': 'STATUS' }
}
```